# Backend Warning: The skip Qobj validation does not work for IBMQ provider. Disable it

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qaoa

I am using QAOA to solve the max-cut problem. On my machine, 10 qubits already takes a minute or two to simulate. I'm hoping that the ibmq-qasm-simulator could simulate 32 qubits faster than my laptop would. Here's my code:

After loading in my IBMQ token and such...

```
optimizer = COBYLA()
# Simulate using IBM's cloud service
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend, shots=1)

part_array = part.values
w = calc_w(part_array)  # Calculate pairwise distances between points

# Execute algorithm
qubit_ops, offset = max_cut.get_max_cut_qubitops(w)
qaoa = QAOA(qubit_ops, optimizer, p)
result = qaoa.run(quantum_instance)
```

While the code runs a message in red (like a warning but without "Warning:") displays saying, "The skip Qobj validation does not work for IBMQ provider. Disable it." How do I do what this message is asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a parameter when instantiating a `QuantumInstance()` called `skip_qobj_validation`. This parameter is set to `True` by default. When creating the QuantumInstance, you can set it to False, and that will get rid of the warning.

```
q_instance = QuantumInstace(skip_qobj_validation=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great!